# Entity Framework not always pulls data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have been working on a website and for the first time started using Entity Framework 6. The application is MVC4, C#.

The issue I am having is that EF not always pulls data from the table. For example I will load a page and get an empty result. But if I refresh the page then the data from database will be shown. If I refresh again it goes empty again.

Basically, it's been pulling data every second time (and been very consistent in this behaviour).

I'm really at lost, I even tried to pull data from view instead of the table, but the behaviour stayed consistent.

Here is the relevant code from my application

```
#region returns list of new files uploaded in the last 24 hours    
    [HttpPost]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public ActionResult LastUploadedFiles()
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath("~/" + this.uploadPath + "/");
        FileListModel filesList = new FileListModel();

        using (CCGFileShareEntities db = new CCGFileShareEntities())
        {
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;


            DateTime daydiff = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24);

            filesList.files = (from r in db.viewFileUploads
                                where r.file_upload_date >= daydiff && r.file_deleted == 0
                                //orderby r.file_upload_date descending
                                select new FileModels()
                                {
                                    id = r.id,
                                    fileName = r.file_name,
                                    file_description = (r.file_description == null ? "" : r.file_description),
                                    upload_extention =  r.upload_extention,
                                    upload_folder = r.upload_folder,
                                    file_upload_date = r.file_upload_date,
                                    upload_owner_id = r.upload_owner_id.ToString(),
                                    file_size = r.file_size.ToString(),
                                    description_is_visible = false
                                }).ToList();

            //get owner and convert date
            FileHelpers fhelpers = new FileHelpers();
            for (int i = 0; i < filesList.files.Count(); i++)
            {
                filesList.files[i].file_upload_date_string = filesList.files[i].file_upload_date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");

                int ownerID = int.Parse(filesList.files[i].upload_owner_id);
                filesList.files[i].fileOnwerName = fhelpers.getUserName(ownerID);
            }

            filesList.currentUserID = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);

                //public string upload_owner_id { get; set; }   


        }

        return Json(filesList);
    }
```

I've no idea why it doesn't pull data every single time as it supposed to do. 
I'm really at loss and would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What does it do when it doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: When you put a break point in the method you posted, does it get hit every time you refresh?

Comment: Three things to do... use db.Connection.Open(); and db.Connection.Close() (close isn't necessary in EF6 but I use it for clarity)... If your posted code is actually firing on every postback I suspect your problem is in the creation of the context, i.e. new CCGFileShareEntities() ... could you please show the constructor?

Comment: @krillgar it returns an empty list with 0 items.

Comment: @neo, it will run and every second time return nothing. But every other time will return records as it should.

Comment: @Dmitris That could just be the FileListModel constructor declaring a new empty list... is your listed code firing on every postback?

Comment: You call ToString method on certain columns. Are you sure that they always have value? Maybe it causes an exception and you just catch it.

Comment: @PaulZahra, yes it is because the values do change and I need to pull latest ones. I'm not sure where to look for the contractor, I've used edmx and generated my model from there.

Comment: @neo, yes the values are there. It is table of uploaded files, I calculate everything upon entry. The only value that is missing is the file description, which I do check for null.

Comment: I have updated the post and placed complete method code

Comment: have you tried to disable IIS cache options ?

Comment: @tschmit007, Yes I've tried it as well. Still getting the same consistent behaviour of returning empty data every second/other time.

Comment: One other thing you can try is to put this query in a command line program in order to eliminate stuff related to postbacks and all. That way you can narrow down your problem.

Comment: @Dmitris Have you ruled out JSon being the issue? If so how?

Comment: @PaulZahra, yes I did, I went and debugged the code to actually see what it returns from database.

Comment: @PaulZahra I think you were right about something in the constructor. I've removed entire edmx and created one from scratch and it is now working as expected with no issues. It was just so strange, the issue was with only this one table, all the other tables are worked as expected.

Comment: @Dmitris Sweet... I assumed that because you hadn't changed constructor it was ok and so didn't mention it again, but as you've found EF can screw things up all by itself :D (it's just as likely that mappings were screwed for the table) ... oh the joys of EF